# How to avoid bars in bar graph getting overlapped with legend

Tags: d3.js

Below is the code which display 'grouped bars' using D3.
the graph also displays a legend at top-right corner.

Bars are overlapping the legend, so, How I can avoid legend getting overlapped with bars, no matter, whatsoever the height of the bars height are?

when I increase the field values, the bars are not growing too high, but they are still overlapping with legend.

```js
var data = [
  {
    model_name: "f1",
    field1: 19,
    field2: 83,
  },
  {
    model_name: "f2",
    field1: 67,
    field2: 200,
  },
  {
    model_name: "f3",
    field1: 200,
    field2: 56,
  },
];

var margin = { top: 30, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 50 },
  width = 500,
  height = 300,
  barPadding = 0.2,
  axisTicks = { outerSize: 0 };

var svg = d3
  .select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height]);

var xScale0 = d3
  .scaleBand()
  .range([margin.left, width - margin.right])
  .padding(barPadding);

var xScale1 = d3.scaleBand(); 

xScale0.domain(data.map((d) => d.model_name));
xScale1.domain(["field1", "field2"]).range([0, xScale0.bandwidth()]);

var yScale = d3
  .scaleLinear()
  .range([height - margin.top - margin.bottom, margin.top]);

yScale.domain([
  0,
  d3.max(data, (d) => (d.field1 > d.field2 ? d.field1 : d.field2)),
]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale0).tickSizeOuter(axisTicks.outerSize);
var yAxis = d3
  .axisLeft(yScale)
  .tickSize(0)
  .tickFormat(function(d) {
    return d + "%";
  });

svg
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - margin.top - margin.bottom})`)
  .call(xAxis);

svg
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},0)`)
  .call(yAxis)
  .call((g) => g.select(".domain").remove());

var model_name = svg
  .selectAll(".model_name")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "model_name")
  .attr("transform", (d) => `translate(${xScale0(d.model_name)},0)`);

model_name
  .selectAll(".bar.field1")
  .data((d) => [d])
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar field1")
  .style("fill", "skyblue")
  .attr("x", () => xScale1("field1"))
  .attr("y", (d) => yScale(d.field1))
  .attr("width", xScale1.bandwidth())
  .attr("height", (d) => {
    return height - margin.bottom - margin.top - yScale(d.field1);
  });

model_name
  .selectAll(".bar.field2")
  .data((d) => [d])
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar field2")
  .style("fill", "orange")
  .attr("x", () => xScale1("field2"))
  .attr("y", (d) => yScale(d.field2))
  .attr("width", xScale1.bandwidth())
  .attr("height", (d) => {
    return height - margin.bottom - margin.top - yScale(d.field2);
  });

var legend_symbol_width = 30;
var legend_symbol_height = 5;
var keys = ["title", "title"];
var color = d3
  .scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(keys)
  .range(["skyblue", "orange"]);

var legend = svg
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width - 20) + ",0)");

keys.forEach(function(key, i) {
  var legendRow = legend
    .append("g")
    // seperating each row of a legend by y axis 20
    .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + i * 20 + ")");

  legendRow
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", -150)
    .attr("y", 10)
    .attr("width", legend_symbol_width)
    .attr("height", legend_symbol_height)
    .attr("fill", color(i));

  legendRow
    .append("text")
    .attr("x", -100)
    .attr("y", 10 + legend_symbol_height * 1.4)
    .style("text-transform", "capitalize")
    .text(key);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to increase the value of the `margin.top` to, for example, 50. This gives more empty space on top of your bars, you there is enough space for the legend.

```js
var data = [
  {
    model_name: "f1",
    field1: 19,
    field2: 83,
  },
  {
    model_name: "f2",
    field1: 67,
    field2: 200,
  },
  {
    model_name: "f3",
    field1: 200,
    field2: 56,
  },
];

var margin = { top: 50, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 50 },
  width = 500,
  height = 300,
  barPadding = 0.2,
  axisTicks = { outerSize: 0 };

var svg = d3
  .select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height]);

var xScale0 = d3
  .scaleBand()
  .range([margin.left, width - margin.right])
  .padding(barPadding);

var xScale1 = d3.scaleBand(); 

xScale0.domain(data.map((d) => d.model_name));
xScale1.domain(["field1", "field2"]).range([0, xScale0.bandwidth()]);

var yScale = d3
  .scaleLinear()
  .range([height - margin.top - margin.bottom, margin.top]);

yScale.domain([
  0,
  d3.max(data, (d) => (d.field1 > d.field2 ? d.field1 : d.field2)),
]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale0).tickSizeOuter(axisTicks.outerSize);
var yAxis = d3
  .axisLeft(yScale)
  .tickSize(0)
  .tickFormat(function(d) {
    return d + "%";
  });

svg
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - margin.top - margin.bottom})`)
  .call(xAxis);

svg
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},0)`)
  .call(yAxis)
  .call((g) => g.select(".domain").remove());

var model_name = svg
  .selectAll(".model_name")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "model_name")
  .attr("transform", (d) => `translate(${xScale0(d.model_name)},0)`);

model_name
  .selectAll(".bar.field1")
  .data((d) => [d])
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar field1")
  .style("fill", "skyblue")
  .attr("x", () => xScale1("field1"))
  .attr("y", (d) => yScale(d.field1))
  .attr("width", xScale1.bandwidth())
  .attr("height", (d) => {
    return height - margin.bottom - margin.top - yScale(d.field1);
  });

model_name
  .selectAll(".bar.field2")
  .data((d) => [d])
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar field2")
  .style("fill", "orange")
  .attr("x", () => xScale1("field2"))
  .attr("y", (d) => yScale(d.field2))
  .attr("width", xScale1.bandwidth())
  .attr("height", (d) => {
    return height - margin.bottom - margin.top - yScale(d.field2);
  });

var legend_symbol_width = 30;
var legend_symbol_height = 5;
var keys = ["title", "title"];
var color = d3
  .scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(keys)
  .range(["skyblue", "orange"]);

var legend = svg
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width - 20) + ",0)");

keys.forEach(function(key, i) {
  var legendRow = legend
    .append("g")
    // seperating each row of a legend by y axis 20
    .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + i * 20 + ")");

  legendRow
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", -150)
    .attr("y", 10)
    .attr("width", legend_symbol_width)
    .attr("height", legend_symbol_height)
    .attr("fill", color(i));

  legendRow
    .append("text")
    .attr("x", -100)
    .attr("y", 10 + legend_symbol_height * 1.4)
    .style("text-transform", "capitalize")
    .text(key);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```